# Identify manufacturer and chip from Canon printer

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit

I'm trying to identify the manufacturer and component from a Canon (printer) I've searched through a couple of logo sites and Google and was not successful.

[image: this chip]

Comment: The map of Texas is a big clue - even to someone from Ireland.

Comment: With respect....if you don't recognize that logo you probably do not have the soldering chops to replace that surface mount chip.  Or to know its actually 'bad.   TI is one of the biggest electronics companies in the world.   Anybody with even moderate experience will have come across their parts.   It'd be like being an auto mechanic but not recognizing the Ford logo...

Answer (score 1):

It's a C2025 manufactured by TI instruments (if I remember right it's a radio chip).

Comment: the word `instruments` is redundant

Comment: Another way to see it is with a redundant I.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a custom IC exclusively for Canon, I suspect made by one of the “excited states”

You can’t buy it but you might dumpster dive for it.